# MySQL Sakila DB, Get list of categories and count in which actor appeared the most

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, where-clause

So I'm learning MySQL, with Sakila DB. Structure is simple,
Tables:actors, actors_films, films, film_categories, categories.

I need to get list of **ALL categories**, and counter how much times Actor appeared in every category. If 0 times, then display row "actions" "0".

Trying this query: `

```
SELECT c2.name genre, COUNT(c2.name) appear 
FROM category c2 
JOIN film_category fc ON c2.category_id = fc.category_id 
JOIN film_actor fa ON fc.film_id = fa.film_id 
JOIN actor a ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id 
WHERE a.actor_id = 1
GROUP by c2.name, c2.category_id
ORDER by appear ASC
```

But this return only categories in which actor appeared, not all of them.
Really appreciate the help
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `left join`s:

```
SELECT c.name genre, COUNT(a.actor_id) appear 
FROM category c 
LEFT JOIN film_category fc ON c.category_id = fc.category_id 
LEFT JOIN film_actor fa ON fc.film_id = fa.film_id 
LEFT JOIN actor a ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id AND a.actor_id = 1
GROUP by c.name, c.category_id
ORDER by appear
```

Notes:

- the filtering on the actor must go the the `on` clause of the relevant `join`, otherwise it filters out categories where the given actor does not appear
- accordingly, you need to count on a column that comes from the actor's table
- `asc` is the default sort order, so there is no need to specify it